# Getting error every time while installation of truffle in window10

Tags: installation, error-handling, npm-install, web3js, truffle

Every time when I try to install Truffle on my PC Windows 10 it's showing npm error install latest verion of vs code and many more things how do I tackle it ?

> npm ERR! code 1
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\Manish Rajput\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\secp256k1
> npm ERR! command failed
> npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
> npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
> npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
> npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | win32 | x64
> npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at "C:\Python310\python.exe"
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32126.315) found at:
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Manish Rajput\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Manish Rajput\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Manish Rajput\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Manish Rajput\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Manish Rajput\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Manish Rajput\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Manish Rajput\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Manish Rajput\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Manish Rajput\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\secp256k1
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Manish Rajput\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-03-30T05_27_30_520Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.